# Makefile - set value to variable from another rule

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

In the following makefile, the `wat` rule is for producing a `.wat` file from a `.c` file.

```
CC=emcc
CFLAGS= -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1
# flags are for not generating any emscripten glue code

# makes a .wat version of a .c file of specified name
# TARGET must be specified from command line
wat: $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET).wasm $(TARGET).c && wasm2wat $(TARGET).wasm > $(TARGET).wat && rm $(TARGET).wasm

struct: TARGET = struct
struct: wat

clear:
    rm -f *.wasm *.wat
```

Called like this, it works fine:

```
[user@pc]$ make wat TARGET=struct
emcc -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o struct.wasm struct.c && wasm2wat struct.wasm > 
struct.wat && rm struct.wasm
```

Now I want a more specific rule, `struct`, written as you see. In essence, I want to reuse the `wat` rule, and just make sure that `TARGET` is set to 'struct' before running. However, running `make struct` gives me a `no input file` error from emcc, as if the value of `TARGET` does not exist:

```
[user@pc]$ make struct
emcc -O2 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1       -o .c
shared:ERROR: no input files
```

What is the correct way to do what I aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that when make evaluates how to make targets and what the prerequisites are, your `TARGET` is undefined and hence the rule says: `wat` needs `.c`. You could try recursion and say something like this:

```
struct:
        $(MAKE) TARGET=struct wat
```

It really isn't that great to start with, because nothing actually generates file `wat` so the target is always out of date and the `Makefile` really is just a somewhat glorified shell script.

You should probably consider writing a pattern rule how to build `.wat` from `.c`, something like (based on your example):

```
%.wat: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(*F).wasm $< \
                && wasm2wat $(*F).wasm > $@.wat \
                && rm $(*F).wasm
```

You then can call `make struct.wat` and if you still wanted (for convenience) have just `struct` target, you could add:

```
.PHONY: struct

struct: struct.wat
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to use target-specific variables and in particular, their inheritance feature, to achieve your goal.

However, this cannot work because of this statement in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).

This means that the `$(TARGET)` in the prerequisite:

```
wat: $(TARGET).c
```

is evaluated when the makefile is parsed, not when the `struct` rule is invoked, and expands to:

```
wat: .c
```

I see that Ondrej provided an answer so I'll stop here :)